# jjil (jon's java image library) which jars needed for Android

Tags: android, image-processing

I'd like to do some image processing in my android app. I'm thinking of using the [jjil library](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/) to do the processing on the bitmaps. However, there seems to be a problem using the jars in an android project. I haven't started using this library yet, but i've seen posts on jjil saying this. I think i just need to copy the src files into my project to use them.

This leads me to my question:

Which src files from which jar do i need to import in order to do image processing in android. Is it just the code from jjil/android or do i need the jjil/core files as well?

Thanks in advance,
Mat